# delete not supported in openrdf workbench

Tags: sesame

I am trying execute following statement in openRDF workbench - 2.6.6

```
delete {
  ?s ?p ?o .
}
```

I get following error:

```
        Encountered " "delete" "delete "" at line 5, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    "base" ...
    "prefix" ...
    "select" ...
    "construct" ...
    "describe" ...
    "ask" ...
```

What should I used then?

EDIT:

I was able to remove statements by clicking remove on left menu. However, I am trying to come up with query to do it programmatic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'SPARQL Update' menu option instead of the 'Query' option.